# Python cap number of occurences of duplicate items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking for a function to limit the number of duplicates in a list. For example in the list below, we have three `'1'`s, one `'2'`, two `'a'`s, and three `'b'`s.

```
initial_list = [1,2,1,1,'a','b','a', 'b','b']

def cap(initial_list, n=2)
```

If I was to limit the number of duplicates to `n=2`, I would get:

```
[1,2,1,'a','b','a', 'b']
```

The order of the items in the output does not matter.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the number of values enountered. You can use dictionary for this (`defaultdict` is even better (UPD: as suggested in the comments `Counter` is even betterer)):

```
from collections import Counter


def cap(initial_list, n=2):
    counter = Counter()
    result = []
    for e in initial_list:
        if counter[e] < n:
            result.append(e)
            counter[e] += 1
    return result

initial_list = [1,2,1,1,'a','b','a', 'b','b']
cap(initial_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `collections.Counter`: check the frequency against the given threshold and update the result with a case-by-case study.

```
from collections import Counter


def cap(initial_list, n=2):
    res = []

    for k, f in Counter(initial_list).items():
        # check frequency of term in list
        if f <= n:
            res.extend([k]*f)
        else:
            res.extend([k]*n)

    return res


initial_list = [1,2,1,1,'a','b','a', 'b','b']

res = cap(initial_list, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

#you can use a dict to count the number of duplicates, without using any librarys

```
def cap(initial_list, n=2):
    counts = {}
    result = []
    for item in initial_list:
        if item not in counts:
            counts[item] = 1
            result.append(item)
        else:
            if counts[item] < n:
                counts[item] += 1
                result.append(item)
    return result

initial_list = [1,2,1,1,'a','b','a', 'b','b']
cap(initial_list, 2)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: You can still save lots of code: `if counts.setdefault(item, 0) < n: counts[item] += 1; ..append..`
No need for the membership test.

Comment: FYI, `collections` is built-in python module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).